# How to remove/backup script from /etc/init.d/?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init.d, ubuntu-11.04

I've been working with linux for a while but in a rather simple manner.

I understand that scripts in `init.d` are executed when the os starts but how exactly does it works?

**What if I want to keep a script but don't want it to start automaticly?**

Say I have a `/etc/init.d/varnish` and want to disable it temporary. How do I make sure it doesn't start if the os reboots? I don't want to delete the script. What if I want to add it again?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are a couple ways. If you just want to do this temporarily, you can remove the execute bit from the file:

```
$ chmod -x /etc/init.d/varnish
```

Then re-add it when appropriate:

```
$ chmod +x /etc/init.d/varnish
```

The "official" way in Ubuntu (as well as in Debian and other Debian derivatives), though, is to use the `update-rc.d` command:

```
$ update-rc.d varnish disable
```

This will remove all of the symlinks from the /etc/rcX.d folders, which take care of starting and stopping the service when appropriate.

See the [update-rc.d man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! `chmod` is an easy solution! I started reading http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html and is helping me understand init. Got me thinking... I should read more of the manual.

Comment: Glad to help. I should note that the chmod solution should *only* be used very temporarily. I haven't verified this, but I could see the Upstart system (what Ubuntu uses to start/stop processes automatically) getting confused by this.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ sudo update-rc.d -f servicename remove
```

Comment: This answer does not match the question which wants to keep the script. “When invoked with the remove option, `update-rc.d` removes any links in the `/etc/rcrunlevel.d` directories to the script `/etc/init.d/name`. The script must have been deleted already.” http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/update-rc.d.8.html